# Show a div onclick and hide the image that triggered it

Tags: javascript, onclick, show-hide

I would like to use the following code to display a hidden div onclick, but then when the it is displayed, I want the image that I used to trigger it to disappear.  Here is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<img src="Icons/note_add.png" onclick="show('comment')"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<div id="comment" style="float:left;display:none;"><textarea name="textfield6" cols="30" rows="2" id="textfield4" class="text"></textarea>&nbsp;<a href="#" class="buttonintable">Submit</a></div>
```

JS:

```
function show(target){
document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';
}
function hide(target){
document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'none';
}
```

How do adjust this to hide the element that fired it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jimmy's answer will work, however to get it to show back up (I assume you want that) you should add an id to the image tag... The following should work.

```
<img id="clickMeId" src="Icons/note_add.png" onclick="show('comment')"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<div id="comment" style="float:left;display:none;"><textarea name="textfield6" cols="30" rows="2" id="textfield4" class="text"></textarea>&nbsp;<a href="#" class="buttonintable">Submit</a></div>

function show(target){
document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById("clickMeId").style.display = 'none';
}
function hide(target){
document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("clickMeId").style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[edited]

**Change the function to this:**

```
function show(this, target){
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';
    this.style.display = 'none';
}
```

**And the onclick attribute to this:**

```
<img onclick="show(this, 'comment')" />
```

Comment: Using `onclick` inline, you do have to pass `this`. When using it as `element.onclick = function;`, you don't, and neither with `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 2):

I rather simplify the context to highlight what matters, inspired by [Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15229884/274502):

```html
<img id="clickMeId" onclick="show('comment'); hide('clickMeId')" alt="click me">

<div id="comment" style="display:none;"> yada yada </div>

<script>
  function show (toBlock){
    setDisplay(toBlock, 'block');
  }
  function hide (toNone) {
    setDisplay(toNone, 'none');
  }
  function setDisplay (target, str) {
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = str;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: How to add fadeIn effect onClick?

Answer (score 1):

Send a second parameter (this) on the "onclick", that would be the image element itself

```
<img src="Icons/note_add.png" onclick="show('comment', this)"/>
```

then the function would apply a "display none" to it:

```
function show(target, trigger){
   document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';
   trigger.style.display = "none"
}
```

But all of this is obtrusive Javascript code, I would recommend you use unobtrusive JS code.

Answer (score -2):

Using jquery this is easy.
   $("#yourdivid").hide();