# fade in and fade out div onclick with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` on left and right of the page. Currently the `div` on the right is being `hidden`.

I'm trying to use jQuery to fadeout the `div` that is currently being displayed and replace it by fading in the `hidden` `div`.

What am I doing wrong? I followed the example on this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251340/onclick-show-div-but-hide-when-other-one-is-clicked).
It should happen when you click the *About* link in the code snippet:

```js
$("a").on('click', function() {
  $("#feed-show").fadeIn();
  $(".feed").fadeOut();
});
```

```css
a {
  color: rgba(255, 80, 70, 1) !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav a {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: rgba(255, 80, 70, 1);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* Content ---------------------*/

/* nav */
.nav {
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  width: 96%;
  left: 2%;
  margin-left: -2px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255, 80, 70, 1);
  padding-bottom: 18px;
  background: white;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0px;
  padding-top: 18px;
}

.c1 {
  max-width: 24%;
}

.column {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 1%;
  width: 585px;
}

/* feed */
.feed {
  width: 96%;
  left: 2%;
  margin-top: 75px;
  padding-left: 2px;
}

.c2 {
  max-width: 49%;
}

.feed-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-top: 2.5%;
}

.feed-show {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: -9999px !important;
  left: -9999px !important;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="nav">
  <div class="column c1">
    <a href="#" rel="click">About</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="feed" class="feed" style="margin-top: 54px;">
  <div class="column c2">
    <p>
      Creatives of Colour (C-oC) is an independent directory that provides you with up to date information on current, and future work of creatives of colour being showcased in the UK. C-oC aims to contribute to the necessary exaltation of talented artists
      within the various ethnic minorities within the UK.
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="#">Find out more about Creatives of Colour..</a>
    </p>
  </div>

  <!-- Show on click -->

  <div id="feed-show" class="feed-show" style="margin-top: 54px;">
    <div class="column c2">
      <p>
        Creatives of Colour (C-oC) is an independent directory that provides you with up to date information on current, and future work of creatives of colour being showcased in the UK.
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Find out more about Creatives of Colour..</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/weXgWm)

Many thanks!

Comment: Your link only goes to the main JSFiddle page.

Comment: @Difster try this - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/weXgWm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have maded some modifications to your code:

I have changed position:absolute to keep hidden #feed-show with display:none

I have changed inside click function fadeIn to be executed when fadeOut is finish to avoid strange moving effect

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#feed-show").fadeOut(0);
  $("a").on('click', function() {
  
     $(".feed").fadeOut(1000,function(){
        $("#feed-show").fadeIn(1000);
     });
  });
});
```

```css
    a {
    color: rgba(255,80,70,1) !important ;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav a {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: rgba(255,80,70,1);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}


/* Content ---------------------*/

/* nav */
.nav {
    position: fixed;
    float:left;
    width: 96%;
    left: 2%;
    margin-left: -2px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255,80,70,1);
    padding-bottom: 18px;
    background: white;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0px;
    padding-top: 18px;
}

.c1 {
    max-width: 24%;
}

.column {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    padding-right: 1%;
    width: 585px;
}

/* feed */
.feed {
    width: 96%;
    left: 2%;
    margin-top: 75px;
    padding-left: 2px;
}

.c2 {
    max-width: 49%;
}

.feed-item {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    padding-top:2.5%;
}
#feed-show{
  display:none;
}
#feed-show p{

   background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
            <div class="column c1">
                <a href="#" rel="click">About</a>
            </div>

        </div>
<div id="container">
        <div id="feed" class="feed" style="margin-top: 54px;">

            <div class="column c2">
                <p>
                    Creatives of Colour (C-oC) is an independent directory
                    that provides you with up to date information on
                    current, and future work of creatives of colour
                    being showcased in the UK. C-oC aims to contribute to the
                    necessary exaltation of talented artists within the various
                    ethnic minorities within the UK.
                </p>
                <p>
                    <a href="#">Find out more about Creatives of Colour..</a>
                </p>
            </div>
   </div>
    <!-- Show on click -->

    <div id="feed-show" class="feed-show" style="margin-top: 54px;">

            <div class="column c2">
                <p>
       OCULT TEXT
                    Creatives of Colour (C-oC) is an independent directory
                    that provides you with up to date information on
                    current, and future work of creatives of colour
                    being showcased in the UK.
                </p>
                <p>
                    <a href="#">Find out more about Creatives of Colour..</a>
                </p>
            </div>


        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly and its a very simple solution! Just a quick question, how would I be able to modify the timing of the fadeIn/fadeOut?

Comment: use first parameter ex: $('#element').fadeOut(1000,function(){//code to execute when fadeout is finish});

Comment: 1000 miliseconds = 1 second

Comment: I have edited and put timing inside (try again the snippet)

Comment: Code-only answers are not very useful.  You've done nothing to explain what you did, how it fixes the issue, etc.  Try adding comments to your code to clarify what you've done.

Comment: I have added also in css #feed-show{display:none} to avoid the ugly flash when enter first time

Comment: @cale_b. I have added some explanations now. I avoid writing too much due to my poor English

Answer (score 2):

You have some problems on your code.

First, your `feed-show` div is inside your `feed` div. So if you `fadeOut()` your `feed` div, everything inside will be hidden.

And second, in your CSS you have absolute position and top and left properties set for your `feed-show`, so even if you `fadeIn()` that element, you're not gonna be able to see it.

I've made a couple of changes on your code, so you can see how one div is fade out and the other one is fade in.

Cheers!

```js
$("a").on('click', function() {
   $("#feed-show").fadeIn();
   $(".feed").fadeOut();
});
```

```css
a {
  color: rgba(255,80,70,1) !important ;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav a {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: rgba(255,80,70,1);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* Content ---------------------*/

/* nav */
.nav {
  position: fixed;
  float:left;
  width: 96%;
  left: 2%;
  margin-left: -2px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255,80,70,1);
  padding-bottom: 18px;
  background: white;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0px;
  padding-top: 18px;
}

.c1 {
  max-width: 24%;
}

.column {
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  padding-right: 1%;
  width: 585px;
}

/* feed */
.feed {
  width: 96%;
  left: 2%;
  margin-top: 75px;
  padding-left: 2px;
}

.c2 {
  max-width: 49%;
}

.feed-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-top:2.5%;
}

.feed-show {
  display: none;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="nav">
  <div class="column c1">
    <a href="#" rel="click">About</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="feed" class="feed" style="margin-top: 54px;">
  <div class="column c2">
    <p>
      Creatives of Colour (C-oC) is an independent directory that provides you with up to date information on current, and future work of creatives of colour being showcased in the UK. C-oC aims to contribute to the necessary exaltation of talented artists
      within the various ethnic minorities within the UK.
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="#">Find out more about Creatives of Colour..</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Show on click -->
<div id="feed-show" class="feed-show" style="margin-top: 54px;">
  <div class="column c2">
    <p>
      Creatives of Colour (C-oC) is an independent directory that provides you with up to date information on current, and future work of creatives of colour being showcased in the UK.
    </p>
    <p>
      <a href="#">Find out more about Creatives of Colour..</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @j this works, however...there seems to be a problem with the fadein and fadeout, its showing the hidden div for a split second on the right hand side before it moves it to the left. This doesn't look too good.

Comment: yeah, but that's CSS/HTML issue... you should modify your CSS code some way so that keeps on the right. At first, it's shown on the right because you have the other div taking the space on the left. but when the left div disappears, then the right div takes that space