# Simplifiying JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I'm running a blog on wordpress. I wish to make #first to disappear when #span1 is clicked but reappear when #second clicked. And #second, #third appear when #span1 clicked but disappear when #second clicked. It works but my questions is it possible to simplify this JQuery to make more simpler and neat. Because probably in future I will have to add more DIVs similar to #third. Other question is how do I control duration of fadeIn and fadeOut?

**HTML**

```js
    $("#span1").on('click', function() {
       $("#second, #third").fadeIn();
       $("#first").hide();
    });
    
    $("#second").on('click', function() {
       $("#first").fadeIn();
       $("#second, #third").hide();
    
    });
```

```html
    <span id="first">Blah blah blah, please <span id="span1">click here</span>.</span>
    <span id="second" style="display:none;">Cancel</span>
    <div id="third" style="display:none;">Test</div>
```

This code is taken from accepted answer from [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251340/onclick-show-div-but-hide-when-other-one-is-clicked).

Comment: This question is more suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the duration, you can either type a number (which represents milliseconds) like this:

```
.fadeIn(400);
```

which performs the action throughout the course of 400ms.
An alternative, is to use a string such as "fast" or "slow", like this:

```
.fadeIn("slow");
```

or

```
.fadeIn("fast");
```

Also, to shorten it (If I have correctly understood your question) you can use this example:

```js
$("#first > span").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().nextAll("div").fadeIn();
  $(this).parent().hide();
});
$("#second").on('click', function() {
  $(this).prev().fadeIn();
  $(this).prev().nextAll().hide();
});
```

```css
.container #second, #first > span {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <span id="first">
    Blah blah blah, please 
    <span>click here.</span>
  </span>
  <div class="hidden" id="second">Cancel</div>
  <div class="hidden" id="third">Test</div>
  <div class="hidden" id="fourth">Test</div>
  <div class="hidden" id="fith">Test</div>
  <div class="hidden" id="sixth">Test</div>
  <div class="hidden" id="seventh">Test</div>
  <div class="hidden" id="eighth">Test</div>
  <div class="hidden" id="ninth">Test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One improvement I could suggest is to cache the selectors in a variable and use those. Like so:

```
$first = $("#first");
$second = $("#second");
$secondThird = $("#second, #third");
$span1 = $("#span1");

$span1.on('click', function() {
   $secondThird.fadeIn();
   $first.hide();
});

$second.on('click', function() {
   $first.fadeIn();
   $secondThird.hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one click event for both operation

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#span1,#second").on('click', function () {
                $("#first,#second, #third").fadeToggle();
            });
        });
```

Comment: OP used `fadeIn` animations instead of hide/show for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

To accommodate for any future divs you could apply a class to all items that should not be visible when `#first` is visible. This way your JS code will not become any longer if you add more divs.

**HTML**

```
<span id="first">Blah blah blah, please <span id="span1">click here</span>.</span>
<span id="second" class="notFirst">Cancel</span>
<div id="third" class="notFirst">Test</div>
<div id="fourth" class="notFirst">Test</div>
<div id="fifth" class="notFirst">Test</div>
<div id="sixth" class="notFirst">Test</div>
<div id="seventh" class="notFirst">Test</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.notFirst {
  display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$("#span1").on('click', function() {
  $(".notFirst").fadeIn(500);
  $("#first").hide();
});

$("#second").on('click', function() {
  $("#first").fadeIn(500);
  $(".notFirst").hide();
});
```

For the duration of the fade effect you can simply add the number of milliseconds, as you can tell from the code.