# Display table row for each user if onclick

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-table

I am struggling with the following.

I have a table with users and when someone clicks on a row, a div should show up right under the line which is clicked and display the information. First I am building up the table:

```
<table id="table" class="table">
        <thead>
            //......
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php $i = 1; foreach ($fetchStudenten as $student){ ?>
            <tr id="student">
                <td><?php echo $i ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $user['student_name'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $user['student_email'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $user['student_id'] ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php if($i == 1){?><tr id="info" colspan="4" style="display: none" class="alert alert-info"><td colspan="4">Display here more info</td></tr><?php } ?>
            <?php $i++; } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

As you can see I enter values for each user in the table. I've tried some (pure!) JS scripts, but I didn't get it to work. Is there any option to perform this in only js, not jQuery?

Comment: yes. Take a look at this answer and let me know if you need help implementing it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15229732/show-a-div-onclick-and-hide-the-image-that-triggered-it

Answer (score 1):

"student" should be a class (ids are unique), than you can do:

```
var students=document.getElementsByClassName("students");
for(var id=0;id<students.length;id++){
  students[id].onclick=function(){
     this.parentNode.rows[ this.rowIndex + 1 ].style.display="block";
  };
}
```

Comment: Declare your variables properly, and don't use `for-in` on arrays or array-like objects. This will visit more than just the matched elements, causing it to fail in some other cases.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. How schould I declare the 'id' in your snippet? as var id=0; and increment it or in another way? By the way, I just saw that I added this in my question code (if $i == 1), but it is supposed to show up for each user.

Comment: @Infiltrator no need to. Just replace id="student" with class="student"

Comment: Tried your solution Jonas, but it doensn't work. So here is again my table body: `code`<tbody>
            <?php $i = 1; foreach ($fetchStudenten as $student){ ?>
                <tr class="student">
                    <td><?php echo $i ?></td>
                    // and 4 other td's
                </tr>
                <tr id="info" style="display: none" class="alert alert-info"><td colspan="4">Test text</td></tr>
                <?php $i++; } ?>
            </tbody> `code` And I only updated your part of the script to dispay: table-row so it would fit better. But nothing shows up..

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Jonas' solution that uses more modern syntax could look like this:

```
for(const s of document.querySelectorAll(".students")) {
  s.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
}

function clickHandler() {
  this.nextElementSibling.style.display = "block";
}
```

Changes made are:

- Used `querySelectorAll` to fetch elements matching the `.students` selector.
- Used the new `for-of` loop to iterate the students.
- Made each student a `const` since there's no intention of modifying that variable.
- Declared the handler function outside the loop so that it can be reused.
- Used `addEventListener()` to bind then handler.
- Used `.nextElementSibling` to get the row after the one clicked.