# how to show content in div once a div is clicked on in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

I wanted to make a content of a div to get displayed once another div is clicked. But I have tried this :

```
function loadFishContent() {
if (div is clicked) {
    document.getElementById('fish').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('dogs').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('cats').style.display = "none";
} 
};
```

I have tried:

```
if (document.getElementByID('menu-fish') == true) {
//do action
}
```

But the action is applied in all the div I clicked.

My html is :

```
<div id="menu-fish" onclick="loadFishContent()"> Fish </div>
<div id="menu-dogs" onclick="loadDogsContent()"> Dogs </div>
<div id="menu-cats" onclick="loadCatsContent()"> Cats </div>

 <div id="content">
            <div id="fish">
            <h2> Fish </h2>
            <img src="fish.jpg"/>
            <p> Information about fish in the store goes here.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="dogs">
            <h2> Dogs </h2>
            <img src="dog.jpg" />
            <p> Information about dogs in the store go here.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="cats">
            <h2> Cats </h2>
            <img src="cat.jpg" />
            <p> Information about cats in the store go here.</p>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Thing is, how do I target the div which is clicked in the if condition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show a div onclick and hide the image that triggered it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15229732/show-a-div-onclick-and-hide-the-image-that-triggered-it)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But they only write "target". How do I actually target the div which is clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you called 3 different methods in your html code, you have to write 3 javascript functions. 
Then you can write code to show and hide div without check of which div clicked, because every div click have different methods to call.

If you wish to do that with a single js method as

```
function loadContent(id) {
if (id=='fish') {
    document.getElementById('fish').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('dogs').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('cats').style.display = "none";
} 
else if (id=='dogs') {
    document.getElementById('fish').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('dogs').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('cats').style.display = "none";
} 
else if (id=='cats') {
    document.getElementById('fish').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('dogs').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('cats').style.display = "block";
} 
};
```

And call that in html as

```
<div id="menu-fish" onclick="loadContent('fish')"> Fish </div>
<div id="menu-dogs" onclick="loadContent('dogs')"> Dogs </div>
<div id="menu-cats" onclick="loadContent('cats')"> Cats </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But how do I actually target the ID of div when it is clicked in the if condition?

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to know! thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Just suggesting cleaner switch approach to an existing answer by crack_iT

```
function loadContent(id) {
    document.getElementById('dogs').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('cats').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('fish').style.display = "none";
    switch (id){
      case 'fish':  document.getElementById('fish').style.display = "block";
                    break;
      case 'cats':  document.getElementById('cats').style.display = "block";
                    break;
      case 'dogs':  document.getElementById('dogs').style.display = "block";
                    break;


    }
};
```

Its a bit more smaller and looks cleaner and easier to understand;

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1:
Update your HTML like below:

```
    <div id="menu-fish" onclick="loadContent('fish')"> Fish </div>
    <div id="menu-dogs" onclick="loadContent('dogs')"> Dogs </div>
    <div id="menu-cats" onclick="loadContent('cats')"> Cats </div>
```

And Update your function as below:

```
    function loadContent(divid) {
        document.getElementById('fish').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('dogs').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('cats').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById(divid).style.display = "block"
    }
```

Approach 2:
If you want id of the div in function then update your HTML like below:

```
    <div id="menu-fish" onclick="loadContent(this)"> Fish </div>
    <div id="menu-dogs" onclick="loadContent(this)"> Dogs </div>
    <div id="menu-cats" onclick="loadContent(this)"> Cats </div>
```

And Update your function as below:

```
    function loadContent(div) {
        var divid = div.id;
        document.getElementById('fish').style.display = divid == 'menu-fish' ? 'block' : "none";
        document.getElementById('dogs').style.display = divid == 'menu-dogs' ? 'block' : "none";
        document.getElementById('cats').style.display = divid == 'menu-cats' ? 'block' : "none";
    }
```

Comment: and where is methods loadDogsContent() and loadCatsContent() are defined?

Comment: Edited my answer. Now you don't need to have separate functions for each div. One single function can work. Please refer edited post and comment if you have further concerns.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using **if/else** as it will be problematic code to manage with 100's of content types.

Use [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```js
/* Create only 1 function for all the content types - pass id as parameter */
function loadContent(id) {
  // Use querySelectorAll to all first level div's, to hide all
  document.querySelectorAll("div#content > div").forEach(el => el.style.display = "none");
 // Now, display the clicked content type
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
div#content > div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-fish" onclick="loadContent('fish')"> Fish </div>
<div id="menu-dogs" onclick="loadContent('dogs')"> Dogs </div>
<div id="menu-cats" onclick="loadContent('cats')"> Cats </div>

<div id="content">
  <div id="fish"><h2> Fish </h2><img src="fish.jpg"/><p> Information about fish in the store goes here.</p></div>
  <div id="dogs"><h2> Dogs </h2><img src="dog.jpg" /><p> Information about dogs in the store go here.</p></div>
  <div id="cats"><h2> Cats </h2><img src="cat.jpg" /><p> Information about cats in the store go here.</p></div>
</div>
```